# OOP beginner: classB extends classA. classA already object. method in classB needed.. etc

Tags: php, oop

I'm learning myself to go from function based PHP coding to OOP. And this is the situation:

`ClassA` holds many basic tool methods (functions). it's `__construct` makes a DB connection.
`ClassB` holds specific methods based on a certain activity (extract widgets). `ClassB` extends `ClassA` because it uses some of the basic tools in there e.g. a database call.

In a php file I create a `$a_class = new ClassA` object (thus a new DB connection).

Now I need a method in `ClassB`. I do `$b_class = new ClassB;` and call a method, which uses a method from it's `parent::`  `ClassA`.

In this example, i'm having `ClassA` 'used' twice. Onces as object, and onces via a `parent::` call, so `ClassA` creates another DB connection (or not?).

So what is the best setup for this basic classes parent, child (extend) situation? I only want to make one connection of course?

I don't like to forward the object to ClassB like this $b_class = new ClassB($a_object); or is that the best way?

Thanks for thinking with me, and helping :d

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO!. This is a design problem, and to help you we need to know more about your problem domain. Just describe what your classes _really_ do.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the comments. I went with setting a 'singleton' $classA = classA::getInstance(); in every classB __construct I have. I hope it helps others who are reading this. :d

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you need the instance of class A at all. Make sure that class B really `is` a class A before using inheritance like this. Look into composition if you aren't sure.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather in your description, it sounds like class B should not really inherit from class A. Ask yourself - is B really an "enhanced version" of A? If not, and B is just using some utility from A, it should only call methods on it, or perhaps compose it (contain it as a member variable.)

As an aside, I don't think you should connect to the database in the constructor of A, unless you put some kind of protection around it to prevent duplicate connections. Probably better to have Connect() and Disconnect() functions so it's well understood when you are and are not connected.

Comment: B is indeed not a enhanced version of A. I use extend because of the easy parent::method() access. What would be the better way to call a method in classA from classB without having to create a new ClassA object 'everytime', assuming that will cause a DB connection from the __constructor.

Could a good solution be in the __construct of classB setting a reference to class A, instead of parent:: accessed via $this->classA?

You are right that __construct should not have a db connection, but it makes my case better :s.

Comment: Yes, when B is constructed it can create a new A and hold onto it in $this->myA. That's what is meant by composition. Of course the situation gets a lot more complicated if multiple objects need access to that same db connection. You don't want everyone creating their own A and making multiple connections. That's why Felix suggested a static connection. But it is also true that overuse of static variables can cause exactly the kind of mess that you're trying to escape.

Answer (score 1):

```
$class_a = new ClassA();
$class_b = new ClassB($class_a);

class ClassB {
    private $class_a;

    public function __construct(ClassA $class_a) {
        $this->class_a = $class_a;
    }
}
```

If I did understand correctly what you wanted to do. This way you can ClassA methods in every method of ClassB without duplicating the connection to the database.

Comment: You do understand it correctly! And this is what I also used for a while, but I think it is not very pretty for such a standard issue! 

Since to access class_b methods, a class_a object needs to be created hence, it's not really a 'blockbox' what I prefer. But if it is standard praktice I can accept.

Comment: You could instantiate ClassA inside ClassB, or if more classes need access to ClassA than you could employ the Singleton/Factory pattern as @solomongaby pointed above.

Comment: @Yvo, mhitza's answer is really sound.  this solution gives you most flexibility and least potential for error.

Answer (score 0):

You could have another object that holds the Db connection that both class A and B can hook to. And its that class responsability to only make a single connection.
You could look into the singleton patter for this